# Gitlab cannot clone repo through 'git clone git@ip:xxx.git'

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, ssh-keys, git-clone

My Gitlab is on the internal network, only IP without domain name.
It is installed by docker, and cannot clone repo through:

```bash
git clone git@ip:xxx.git
```

and can been cloned through:

```bash
git clone http://ip:xxx
```

I have add SSH Key in my Gitlab, and if I clone repo by `git clone git@ip:xxx.git`. it will display

```bash
Cloning into 'xxx'...
Warning: Permanently added 'ip' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@ip's password:
```

**No matter what password entered, you cannot clone this repo.**

---

run Docker container by

```bash
docker run --detach \
  --hostname ip \
  -p 8443:443 -p 8090:80 -p 8022:22 \
  --name gitlab-ee \
  --restart always \
  --volume /mnt/data01/opt/gitlab-ee/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume /mnt/data01/opt/gitlab-ee/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume /mnt/data01/opt/gitlab-ee/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  --privileged=true \
  gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
```

The file about ~/.ssh/config is :

```
  # gitlab
  Host ip
      HostName ip
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

I have try to clone through

```bash
git clone http://ip:xxx
```

However,it is not convenient to use because always needs to enter account and password.

Comment: Have you added your public key to your account on that GitLab instance?